# TypeError: string indices must be integers // working with JSON as dict in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, youtube, typeerror

Okay, so I've been banging my head on this for the last 2 days, with no real progress. I am a beginner with python and coding in general, but this is the first issue I haven't been able to solve myself.

So I have this long file with JSON formatting with about 7000 entries from the youtubeapi. 
right now I want to have a short script to print certain info ('videoId') for a certain dictionary key (refered to as 'key'):

**My script**:

```
import json

f = open ('path file.txt', 'r')
s = f.read()

trailers = json.loads(s)
print(trailers['key']['Items']['id']['videoId'])
# print(trailers['key']['videoId'] gives same response
```

**Error:**

```
print(trailers['key']['Items']['id']['videoId'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It does work when I want to print all the information for the dictionary key:
This script **works**

```
import json

f = open ('path file.txt', 'r')
s = f.read()

trailers = json.loads(s)
print(trailers['key'])
```

Also *print(type(trailers))* results in *class 'dict'*, as it's supposed to.

My JSON File is formatted like this and is from the youtube API, youtube#searchListResponse.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "",
 "nextPageToken": "",
 "regionCode": "",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": ""
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "",
    "channelId": "",
    "title": "",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

What other information is needed to be given for you to understand the problem?

Comment: can you try `print(trailers['key']['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])` as `items` is a list of dict

Comment: 1. "Items" should be lowercase shouldn't it? 2. Note how "items" contains a list of objects, not a single object.

Comment: As an aside, you should just use `with open('path file.txt') as f: trailers = json.load(f)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's the same thing but more 'pythony' written right? Also is json.load insteadd of json.loads on purpose?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes it should be, changed that. That's true I suppose, but how do I act on that?

Comment: Yes. `json.load` is used directly with the file handler. `json.loads` takes a **s**tring

Comment: @Lourens Grab the first element of "items" using `[0]`, then index the dictionary with the key. The answer already covers how to fix it.

Comment: @pramod  hm yes it is a list of dict, but that didn't work. For my own knowledge, what's the thinking behind the [0]?

Comment: @Lourens as items is a list, so items[0] will give me first value in that list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay makes sense thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate okay, so following up on that, it still gives me the same error... Do you have a clue? Do I have to index the first element of 'items' (i dont think thats it) because it's a dict containing a dict (id).

Comment: Wait, where is "key" in the JSON? Are you missing data?

Comment: @pramod so after using thomasedv's answer I found out that items isnt a list nor a dict, but a str. Does this mean my data is useless or is there a (relatively) easy way to get what i want. If not I'm going to keep looking and find a way around, so thanks for the help! If yes, I'm hoping you can share tell me

Comment: @Carcigenicate No what I've shown there is the response of `print(trailers['key']` so that's why it doesnt show the key. The data is there, but it looks like it's one big string, not even a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gives me all the videoId's from the provided sample data (which is no id's at all in fact):

```
import json

with open('sampledata', 'r') as datafile:
    data = json.loads(datafile.read())
print([item['id']['videoId'] for item in data['items']])
```

Perhaps you can try this with more data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you answer! This is indeed the way to go, I figured that out myself a couple days after this thread died down. To be specific, the problem was that I had 1 textfile which contained a dictionary of all the 7000 api results. I shouldve done json.loads on each entry (the api result) in the dictionary. Silly mistakes, but super confusing when I started out coding.

Comment: Hehe, yes, makes sense. Have you already added `ptpython` and `pudb` to your python toolkit? They might help you nail down these things quicker in the future.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really look into the youtube api but looking at the code and the sample you gave it seems you missed out a [0]. Looking at the structure of json there's a list in key *items*.

```
import json

f = open ('json1.json', 'r')
s = f.read()

trailers = json.loads(s)
print(trailers['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])
```

Comment: assuming you forget ['key'] there, but I still get the same error. Although I think it's unrelated, I'm importing from a .txt file. Shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: I intentionally left out the ['key'] because there is no 'key' in the sample you supplied. And yes, you can use a .txt file. BTW you can always try `trailers['items']`, `trailers['items'][0]`, `trailers['items'][0]['id']` ... to pin point the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've not used json before at all. But it's basically imported in the form of dicts with more dicts, lists etc. Where applicable. At least from my understanding.

So when you do `type(trailers)` you get type dict. Then you do dict with `trailers['key']`. If you do type of that, it should also be a dict, if things work correctly. Working through the items in each dict should in the end find your error.

Pythons error says you are trying find the index/indices of a string, which only accepts integers, while you are trying to use a dict. So you need to find out why you are getting a string and not dict when using each argument.

Edit to add an example. If your dict contains a string on key 'item', then you get a string in return, not a new dict which you further can get a dict from. `item` in the json for example, seem to be a list, with dicts in it. Not a dict itself.

Comment: I think I've found the problem with your answer, If I do `type(trailers['key'])` I get type str. Not even a list, so I can't index it, it will only get a single character.

Comment: So, when you print the whole `trailer`, does it show what's under the 'key' key? Could you edit the question to show everything that's printed for `print(trailer)`?